# Multi-query multiple DNS record types at once

Tags: domain-name-system, dns-lookup

I am currently experimenting a bit with the DNS protocol. I have noticed that I can query both, A- and MX-record of a domain, using two separate DNS packets, each containing one question query. However, when I chain them together within the question section so that the question section of a single DNS packet contains two queries, the reply to my request will only return the A-record of the domain.

E.g. The query "A test.com" returns the IP address of test.com and "MX test.com" returns the mail exchange server. But the query "A test.com, MX test.com" only returns the IP address.

Why is that the case?

Comment: Can you please share of how could you chain two queries in one packet

Comment: You would just set the number of questions in the packet to two instead of one and append a second query. Hint: Look at a DNS query in Wireshark.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The short answer is it's allowed in the protocol, but practically not supported.
For more details you can see the below similar question/answer.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4083071/3042552